# Can't get responseText from $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to get a string from the server using jquery $.post, the issue is that I can't get the responseText from it.
So if I run

```
role = $.post('user_helper/return_current_role', {id: 3}, null, "json").responseText;
console.log(role);
```

I get `undefined`
If I try

```
role = $.post('user_helper/return_current_role', {id: 3}, null, "json");
console.log(role);
```

I get an object `Object { readyState=1, getResponseHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}`, where responceText is, for example, `teacher`.
Here is this response, copied from firebug:

```
readyState
    4

responseText
    "teacher"

status
    200

statusText
    "OK "
```

Comment: The log of role says `readyState` is 1. But your firebug report says `4`. What is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it's asynchronous, and has a callback function, how about:

```
$.post('user_helper/return_current_role', {id: 3}, function(result) {
    var role = result;
    console.log(role);
}).fail(function(a,b,c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
});
```

You can not use the result of an ajax call, until it's returned from the server.
It's just how asynchronous calls work!

**EDIT:**

chained on a fail method, see if that tells you anything ?

Comment: Then your ajax call probably failed. I'll add a fail method as well, try and see what that does ?

Comment: @Starx - same origin policy, for one ?

Comment: `parsererror
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected keyword
 

return window.JSON.parse( data );`

Comment: Accoring to OP's firebug result, it has `teacher` on its reponseText. So both 1 and 2 are not the correct in this case.

Comment: You need to pass valid JSON, if all you're passing it the string "teacher" that's not valid JSON at all, so change the dataType to text instead, or just remove it all together.

Comment: edited the answer, and removed the dataType. You could also just pass valid JSON.

Comment: @Starx -`reponseText` is part of the XHR object, and if it only consists of a string, it would be invalid when the dataType is JSON.

Comment: Sorry, the response was realty a string. Changed it to 'text' and got it solved. Thanks once more.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way too:

```
$.post('user_helper/return_current_role', {id: 3}, function(data) {
   var role = data; 
   // Now Do what you need
}, "json");
```